# Gradient color segmented control in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, segmentedcontrol

I need your help.

I want to do gradient background color segmented controls in xamarin forms like this screenshot. 
How can i do that? 
Any idea? 
Thank you.

[image: Screenshot]

Alternative link: [Alternative link](https://pasteboard.co/I5GQ1mz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PancakeView:
https://github.com/sthewissen/Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView

This View supports rounded corner, shadow and gradients (with start and end color, plus gradient angle).

You can have a `PancakeView` for background (with white background, rounded corner and shadow) and inside a `StackLayout` (or `Grid`) with two `Label` "Existing user" and "New user".
Every `Label` with a `GestureRecognizer` so when is tapped you can display another `PancakeView` with gradient background between the Label and the PancakeView in background.

You have to embed everything in a `Grid` so you can display layers on top eachoter. It could be tricky to micromanage but it is doable without too much effort.

Comment: Thank you. It will very helpful

Comment: @muhammetsahin i'm happy to help :) if this solve your question dont forget to mark the answer :)